# Highcharts legend js error

Tags: highcharts

I am working with Highstock.js and prototype adapter. When I try to construct a stacked column chart on a specific data set I see the below js error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined 
(anonymous function)    
(anonymous function)    
HighchartsAdapter.each  
Legend.handleOverflow   
Legend.render               
Legend.init                 
Highcharts.Legend       
Chart.render                
Chart.firstRender           
Chart.init                  
(anonymous function)        
obj.(anonymous function)    
(anonymous function)         
obj.(anonymous function) 
Chart
```

I have reproduced that in http://jsfiddle.net/arjunbadarinath/f8JzU/6/,  if I remove some stackings, the chart renders and also it renders when I remove the legend 'maxHeight' property, but removing this is not an option for us.

Can you please figure out what the problem is?

Comment: So how we can replicate your issue?

Comment: I am able to reproduce it on jsfiddle now, please check it out.

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arjunbadarinath/f8JzU/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `color:['#ffffff']` with `color:'#ffffff'`

http://jsfiddle.net/f8JzU/7/

Comment: Issue is reproducible even if we remove the array, I think its a bug in Higshtock 1.3.9. The same works of you change it to 1.3.10.

Comment: But it was workaround, so you can update to the 1.3.10 or use string instead of array.

Comment: Even with the workaround the problem happens on 1.3.9, it is a bug in 1.3.9. Replacing array with string has no effect on this issue.